# Navigation component navigate method not working after Admob Interstitial displayed

Tags: android, admob, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am creating an android application with `Navigation Component` implementation. The workflow of `SplashFragment` (which is startDestination) is that `onViewCreated` `Admob Interstitial` request is sent and AD displayed, on ad close i want to navigate the app to `DashboardFragment`. The navigation works fine when Admob AD is not displayed but after Admob AD displayed the navigation never works and UI is stuck on `SplashFragment`.

What i tried?

- I tried to resolve this issue by navigating the fragment `onAdShowedFullScreenContent`  instead of `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent` but this results in showing a black screen before Admob AD display.

Below is my code

**SplashFragment**

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {
    private var onFinishedFirstCall: Boolean = false

    //max wait time is 10 seconds
    val SPLASH_TIME_SHORT_WITHOUT_AD = 2000
    private var isAdMobIntLoaded = false


    var handler = Handler()
    private val repository = get<Repository>()
    var interstitialadMobAd: InterstitialAd? = null

    var isShow = false
    private val sharedViewModel: MainViewModel by sharedViewModel()
    private val tinyDB = get<TinyDB>()
    var isRemoteConfigLoaded = false
    var isInitialSetupDone = false

    var timer: CountDownTimer? = null
    var counter = 4
    private var timerStart = false
    var remaining: Long = 6000
    var isAdReqCompleted = false


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash_screen_layout, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        nativeRemoteCheck()
    }

    private fun nativeRemoteCheck() {
        repository.onRemoteConfigLoadedListener.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            object : Observer<Boolean> {
                override fun onChanged(isLoaded: Boolean?) {
                    //reset saved ad request info which was saved to avoid ad recalls on connectivity changes
                    resetAdRequestInfo(tinyDB)
                    if (isLoaded!!) {
                        isRemoteConfigLoaded = true
                        initialScreenSetup()
                    }

                }
            })
    }

    private fun initialScreenSetup() {
        //Remote config response receive; now proceed
        //if purchased or no connectivity proceed with 2 seconds delay
        val isInternetConnected = requireContext().isNetworkAvailable()
        if (sharedViewModel.getIsPurchased() || !isInternetConnected) {
            isInitialSetupDone = true
            setupTimer(2000)
        } else {
            setupTimer(10000)
            //not purchased and internet is also connected
            sharedViewModel.getSplashIntersConfig()
                .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                    if (it.show) {
                        isInitialSetupDone = true
                        //if splash interstial is enabled then send request
                        adMobExtensionFuntion()
                    } else {
                        isInitialSetupDone = true
                        //if splash interstial ad is not enabled proceed with 2 seconds delay
                        handler.postDelayed({
                            nextPage()
                        }, SPLASH_TIME_SHORT_WITHOUT_AD.toLong())
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    private fun nextPage() {
        try {
            val navHostFragment =
                activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.main_navigation_graph) as NavHostFragment
            val navController = navHostFragment.navController
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_splash_to_dashboard)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {

        }
    }

    fun adMobExtensionFuntion() {
        context?.loadAdmobInterstitial(
            AdPlacement.SPLASH,
            context?.getString(R.string.admob_Splash_int)!!,
            {
                interstitialadMobAd = it
                sharedViewModel.onIntAdSuccess.postValue(true)
                isAdMobIntLoaded = true
                isAdReqCompleted = true
                interstitialadMobAd?.fullScreenContentCallback =
                    object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            nextPage()

                        }

                        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {

                        }

                        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            
                        }

                    }
            },
            {
                isAdReqCompleted = true
                nextPage()

            }
        )
    }


    fun setupTimer(duration: Long) {
        timerStart = true
        timer = object : CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.e("timer1 :", ": ${millisUntilFinished}")
                remaining = millisUntilFinished
                if (interstitialadMobAd != null) {
                    onFinish()
                }
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                onFinishedFirstCall = true
                if (interstitialadMobAd != null) {
                    interstitialadMobAd?.show(activity)
                    timer?.cancel()
                } else {
                    if (interstitialadMobAd == null && !isAdReqCompleted) {
                        nextPage()
                    }
                    timer?.cancel()
                }

            }

        }.start()
    }
```

**Navigation Graph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splash_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splash_fragment"
        android:name="mypkgname.ui.splash.SplashFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/splash_screen_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splash_to_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/dashboard_fragment"
            />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_fragment"
        android:name="mypkgname.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/test_dashboard_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dashboard_to_videoplayer"
            app:destination="@id/videoplayer_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_animation" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/videoplayer_fragment"
        android:name="mypkgname.ui.videoplayer.VideoPlayerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_videoplayer_layout">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_videoplayer_to_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/dashboard_fragment"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"

            />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

*Please note i am using this sdk version of Admob*

```
 api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
```

I am unable to figure out the cause of this issue. Can somebody please help me out with this.

Thank you

Comment: this might be happening due to disallowed interstitial implementation https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-after-page-load

Comment: @AmodGokhale i dont think this one lies in disallowed interstitial implementation because this is actually showing between two activities